# HTML formatting not working in header/footer of printed interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid that I'm trying to print in PDF format.
In the grid's printing properties, I typed some HTML code, which didn't get interpreted for some reason, the text was printed but the HTML tags and CSS formatting were just ignored, is there a way to fix that?

I'm on APEX 22.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Page Header Text and Page Footer Text properties, you can enter text and page/app items. HTML and CSS are not supported for these attributes.

[image]